# Extract geometric figures from javascript ascii array

Tags: javascript, arrays, geometry, ocr

I'd like to code a kind of OCR-reader (*like Snapchatcode --> dotcode reader*). 
PS: How my scanner is working is incidental for this question.

However: The result from my scanner function is something like this but as array:

> ----------------------------------
>   -----------------####-----------
>   ---#------------#-----------#----
>   -###----------####-----###--
>   --#------------#------------#---
>   ---------------####------------
>   ---------------------------------
>   ---------------------------------
>   ---------------------------------

I hope you can get the '**E**'-character above.
...Ok, sooo i'd like to get the exact character position from the resultstring for all **#-characters** of the '**E**'-char.

So in this example ...

- 34chars (first row)
- 18. char of second row: '#'

... I'd like to get something like this:

- 52, 53, 54, 55, 83, ... (All #-chars that belong to the 'E')

`var resultarray=[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ']`...

Is there an easy method/way to find such **special figures** in the result array?

I would be very grateful for links to methods or suggestions for codes.

Comment: So you want to find the connected components? Simple BFS or DFS should work.

Comment: Sounds good, but I don't get how to use BFS on javascript (ascii) strings. Can you give me a short code example :-) Greetings @NicoSchertler

Comment: @jo byom Do you understand how to use BFS with arrays? Just work with string like array of chars.

Comment: Ok but I really have no clue how to use BFS on strings or arrays. Do you can share a link or a simple code snipped please? @MBo

Comment: OK. Do you understand how BFS works at all? You need to check for neighbor elements. How to get neighbors for A[i] where A[] array/string representing WxH matrix?

Comment: Ok.. I know how to use BFS, but I don't get how to use BFS on my arrays-string. I really need some code to understand this :0